# Missing Reference Exception with Rigidbody Field and ?? operator

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, nullreferenceexception, rigid-bodies

I keep getting this exception :
"MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'Rigidbody' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it."

The problem with it is that i only accsess it by this field :

```
    private Rigidbody m_Rigidbody = null;
    private Rigidbody Rigidbody => m_Rigidbody ?? (m_Rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>());
```

and my exception is thrown at this line :

```
    public float CurrentSpeed => (Rigidbody?.velocity.magnitude ?? 0f) * ((m_SpeedType == SpeedType.MPH)?2.23693629f : 3.6f);
```

What my question is, how is it possible that i get a null reference, even if the object has a rigidbody (every object that throws this exception still has its rigidbody active and attached if the error occures).

Thanks in advance and have a nice day.

Comment: That line shouldn't throw a null reference exception since you are using the null-safety operator. Are you sure that the access to `Rigidbody` is what is throwing the exception?

Comment: Yes this is exactly what bothers me.
The message says exactly : 
"MissingReferenceException: [...] CarControl.CarHandling.CarMove.get_CurrentSpeed () (at Assets/Scrips/StateMachineImplementation/RoadUsers/CarControl/CarHandling/CarMove.cs:52)"
And at line 52 in CarMove is the given Field "CurrentSpeed"

Comment: MissingReferenceException isn't quite the same as NullReferenceException. I suspect that `Rigidbody` refers to an actual object, but one that you've called `Destroy` on. (Not that I'm a Unity developer, but it looks like that would explain things.)

Comment: That is a good point, since it occures every time i delete an object but this exception is called on every car afterwards like it would be a static script which it isn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You shouldn't use `?` or `??` on anything inheriting from `UnityEngine.Object` AT ALL.**

It is somehow related to how Unity implemented their [`==`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object-operator_eq.html) and [`!=`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object-operator_ne.html) operators internally for [`UnityEngine.Object`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.html) (which is basically the super class for any Component, GameObject, Asset etc)

See also [Possible unintended bypass of lifetime check of underlying Unity engine object](https://github.com/JetBrains/resharper-unity/wiki/Possible-unintended-bypass-of-lifetime-check-of-underlying-Unity-engine-object) where the makers of the Re-Sharper Plug-In for Unity explained it further based on [UnityBlog - "Custom == operator, should we keep it?"](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/05/16/custom-operator-should-we-keep-it)

Checking for `==null` and thereby also and in particular using the [`?`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) and [`??`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) operators is simply **bypassed** by `UnityObject`.

**Why?**

On the surface: After calling `Destroy` (or e.g. if it is a serialized field and not referenced yet) an `Object`  in Unity does not exist anymore. **BUT** it is **not** really `==null`, it rather still holds some meta data and is only - how they state it

> a `fake null object`.

That's actually the reason why you do not get a `NullReferenceException` but the Unity built-in `MissingReferenceException` giving you a hint **why** you usually would get a `NullReferenceException` at this point. It could e.g. state

> The object of type 'XY' was destroyed but you are still trying to access it

---

However in particular for this reason `UnityEngine.Object` has an implicit [`bool` operator](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object-operator_Object.html) returning

> Does the object exist?

so e.g. `if(destroyedObject)` after `detroyedObject` has been called `Destroy(destroyedObject);` or it is is a field that was never assigned yet will now not be executed (anymore) since it is now `false`.

---

So what you want to do especially for stuff being `Destroy`ed would be actually using that operator like

```
private Rigidbody m_Rigidbody = null;
private Rigidbody Rigidbody
{
    get
    {
        if(m_Rigidbody) return m_Rigidbody;

        m_Rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

        return m_Rigidbody;
    }
}
```

For readability reasons I'm not a fan of making things like this an expression body anyway.

Your other property would then accordingly also be

```
public float CurrentSpeed => Rigidbody ? Rigidbody.velocity.magnitude * ((m_SpeedType == SpeedType.MPH) ? 2.23693629f : 3.6f) : 0f;
```

---

In general any my opinion: Whenever there might be more work hidden inside a property then only simplifying references (like here e.g. `GetComponent`) it should rather be a method. But maybe this is just a matter of taste.

Comment: Thanks didn't know about that yet.